# Javascript: How can I put SVG images into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg

Say I had three circles - one red, one yellow and one green.

```
    <svg height="100" width"100"=""> <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "3" fill="red "></circle> </svg>

    <svg height="100" width"100"=""> <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "3" fill="yellow"></circle> </svg>  

    <svg height="100" width"100"=""> <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "3" fill="green"></circle> </svg>
```

Is it possible to create an array that has these 3 included in it? 
If not, can you recommend a way I can create an array that includes three circles that are red, yellow and green?

Many thanks

Comment: The syntax of your elements is broken (`...width"100"=""...`).

Comment: `var svgImages = document.querySelectorAll('svg');`

Comment: When you say 'you have 3 circles', do you mean you have them in a rendered html page (inline), as link targets in some html/xml, or textually in a (JS) string ?

Comment: @collapsar textually in a JS string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need them in an array first get their parent element. Let's call it `svgParent` then do like this.

```
var svgArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(svgParent.querySelectorAll("svg"));
```

you should get the three svg elements in a proper array. We are using `element.querySelectorAll()` from the parent because in case other svg elements exist we don't want to collect the svg elements other than these three.

Answer (score 0):

```
<svg height="100" width="100"> <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "3" fill="red "></circle> </svg>

    <svg height="100" width="100"> <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "3" fill="yellow"></circle> </svg>  

    <svg height="100" width="100"> <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "3" fill="green"></circle> </svg>
```

JS code

```
var svgArray = document.querySelectorAll('svg');

console.log(svgArray[0]); // svgArray[0] is red circle
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b9mysaew/ Demo for you (check console)

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns `NodeList` which is `array-like` object.. not `array`..

Comment: and what is the problem with `array-like` object? or do you think it is very important for @DragonSlayer to get a real `Array`, if he doesn't know  how to find DOM elements? LOL

Comment: @AndrewEvt I already had it in a DOM element. My question is whether I can contain it in an array.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll('svg');`or `document.getElementsByTagName('svg')` can be use to put all the `svg` elements in an array like object.

`document.querySelectorAll()` will return a `NodeList` while

`document.getElementsByTagName('')` will return `HTMLCollection`

Answer (score 0):

1- Create a parent SVG element

2- Bind data to the svg and enter()

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + 20);

var circles = svg.selectAll(".month")
    .data(eachcircle);
//loop from 0 to eachcircle.length
circlesdata(eachcircle).append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return d[["x"];}) 
    .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return d["y"];})
    .attr("r", function (d) { return d["r"]; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d["color"]; });
```

Comment: The question is not tagged with d3

Comment: Sorry, I new here.